# Program hanging on Dispatcher.Run() c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm using this code to run ProgressBar in separate thread.

```
ProgresBarForm viewer = new ProgressBarForm("Wait");    
Thread viewerThread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        viewer = new ProgressBarForm("Wait");
        viewer.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

viewerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); // needs to be STA or throws exception
viewerThread.Start();
```

Then i'm doing some long operation and when i finish i'm invoking this code:

```
viewer.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => window.Close()));
```

and it works really well but when I close my window debugger is not stopping. In VS 2012 I click "Break All" button and it occurs that program is hanging on line

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
```

How can I close this dispatcher to exit from my program?

Thanks in advance for all responses.

Comment: This is not how you should be doing this. Your form should be running on a GUI thread. It's the long background processing operation (whatever that is) that should be running on a different thread, and invoke progress bar updates on the GUI thread. The simple way is to use a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use BackgroundWorker. The problem is that this long operation has to be done alone, because next steps in program depends on this long operation.

Comment: Of course next steps depend on the operation being finished. I think that's how any background running operation works. Stuff depends on it being done. But I don't see what this has to do [with using a `BackgroundWorker`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   viewer.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => window.Close()));
```

That isn't good enough to get the dispatcher to stop.  Your "viewer" is a Winforms Form, not a WPF window.  So the normal shutdown mechanism can't work.  You have to help and *also* tell the dispatcher to quit:

```
   viewer.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
       System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
       viewer.Close();
   }));
```

Do beware the race, the user might close your WPF window before you get a chance to call this code.  Visions of DoEvents() misery abound.  So you probably should *also* set the thread's IsBackground property to *true*.  And do beware the problems with displaying UI on a worker thread, you have to carefully craft your "progress" form so it doesn't use any of the dangerous controls in the toolbox.  The ones that use the SystemEvents class.  Or you get to debug a deadlock [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).

This forever works better and more reliably if you do *not* let your UI thread do the heavy work.  Let it take care of *just* the UI, do the heavy lifting in a worker thread.

Comment: First of all thank you for your valuable time. It works. As you suggested I also set IsBackground to true.

Answer (score 5):

Because your thread is a foreground thread, which is enough to keep your process alive.

Make it a background thread by setting `viewerThread.IsBackGround = true`, so that it will not be able to keep your process alive.

Or inside the callback where you close the window, simply call `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown` after closing the window.

Comment: The latter suggestion is actually better. Making the thread background will only allow CLR to abort it, but OP's problem is that the thread is stuck inside the call to `Dispatcher.Run`.

Comment: viewerThread.IsBackground = true actually helps but it is safe to use?

InvokeShutdown doesn't work. (i'm caliing this function in FormClosing event like System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();